# ResNet50 torchvision implementation gives low accuracy on CIFAR-10

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, resnet, torchvision

I am new to Deep Learning and PyTorch. I am using the resnet-50 model in the torchvision module on cifar10. I have imported the CIFAR-10 dataset from torchvision. The accuracy is very low on testing and I have tried configuring the classification layers but there is no change in the accuracy. Is there something wrong with my code? Am I making a mistake in calculating the accuracy?

```
import torchvision
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim
import os
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

transformations=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
trainset=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./CIFAR10',download=True,transform=transformations,train=True)

testset=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./CIFAR10',download=True,transform=transformations,train=False)

trainloader=DataLoader(dataset=trainset,batch_size=4)
testloader=DataLoader(dataset=testset,batch_size=4)

inputs,labels=next(iter(trainloader))
labels=labels.float()
inputs.size()

print(labels.type())
resnet=torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

if torch.cuda.is_available():
  resnet=resnet.cuda()
  inputs,labels=inputs.cuda(),torch.Tensor(labels).cuda()

outputs=resnet(inputs)
outputs.size()

for param in resnet.parameters():
  param.requires_grad=False

numft=resnet.fc.in_features
print(numft)
resnet.fc=torch.nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(numft,1000),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(1000,10))
resnet.cuda()
resnet.train(True)
optimizer=torch.optim.SGD(resnet.parameters(),lr=0.001,momentum=0.9)
criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range(5):
    resnet.train(True)

    trainloss=0
    correct=0
    for x,y in trainloader:
        x,y=x.cuda(),y.cuda()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        yhat=resnet(x)
        loss=criterion(yhat,y)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        trainloss+=loss.item()



    print('Epoch: {} Loss: {}'.format(epoch,(trainloss/len(trainloader))))

    accuracy=[]
    running_corrects=0.0
    for x_test,y_test in testloader:

        x_test,y_test=x_test.cuda(),y_test.cuda()
        yhat=resnet(x_test)
        _,z=yhat.max(1)
        running_corrects += torch.sum(y_test == z)

    accuracy.append(running_corrects/len(testloader))

print(running_corrects/len(testloader))
accuracy=max(accuracy)
print(accuracy)
```

**OUTPUT AFTER TRAINING/TESTING**

```
Epoch: 0 Loss: 1.9808503997325897
Epoch: 1 Loss: 1.7917569598436356
Epoch: 2 Loss: 1.624434965057373
Epoch: 3 Loss: 1.4082191940283775
Epoch: 4 Loss: 1.1343850775527955
tensor(1.1404, device='cuda:0')
tensor(1.1404, device='cuda:0')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of my observations:

1. You may want to fine-tune learning-rate and number of epochs and batch size. For example, currently you are training your model for only five epochs which might not be sufficient to achieve high accuracy. you can try with lager value of epochs.
2. Have you tried adapting backbone (feature extractor) model for CIFAR10 dataset by setting `param.requires_grad=True? Because the original model is trained on imagenet that might need to adapt on CIFAR10.
3. Before evaluation/testing you may like to set `resnet.train(False)` or `resnet.eval()` to let the model know that you are in eval mode. Furthermore, you may want to evaluate your model under the scope of `no_grad()` by using `with torch.no_grad():` that will speed up inference time and reduce memory usage.
4. [**CIFAR-10 is a balanced dataset so it's an optional (EDA) task here.**] Have you checked the class distribution of CIFAR10 in terms of whether it's an imbalanced dataset or not? If it's an imbalanced dataset you may want to employ weighted cross entropy for you loss calculation. There are other strategies to tackle class-imbalance like over-sampling or under-sampling.

Regarding test accuracy, You need to divide the total number of correct prediction by the total number of samples in the dataset, `len(testloader.dataset)` instead of `len(testloader)`. If you want your accuracy in the range of `[0,100]`, just multiply by 100. You can print test accuracy for each epoch to check how it's changing whereas you are currently showing the maximum accuracy.

Comment: According to the OP's output, the accuracy is 1.1404, which would be 114%. That is definitely not okay. The real accuracy is roughly 0.285 (28.5%), because `len(testloader) = len(testset) / batch_size`. Also [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) is balanced (6000 images per class). Other than that, it's good advice, although I would rank number of epochs and batch size a lot higher.

Comment: Thank you @bit01 for the advice. I find the answer very helpful. Let me just try it out and I will let you know if I have any further problems. Thank you so much for taking the time out to read my code and solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelJungo for your insights as well!